# PHP : GoogleSheet into database, handle blank cells

Tags: php

I have a weird problem...

I get datas from a GoogleSheet with the API. Then I insert those data in a database.

But the problem, it's when I insert those data in the database, the blank cells are replaced by the above data. I don't want it, if I have a blank cell, I want to insert it in the database like a null value.

For example in this picture, when I insert the data, that will insert "cynthia itua" and not just "cynthia" :[firstname / lastname](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BpyRy.png)

Here a screenshot of the table. [Table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ycAn.png)

What I need to do ?

Here my code :
The StrAdaptator, DataAdaptator and PhoneAdaptator are just few class to format the data.

```
    public function eventsData()
    {
        $range = 'Events';
        $values = [];
        Sheetapi::getSpreadsheetData($values, $range);

        if (empty($values)) {
            print "No data found.\n";
        } else {

            $keys = array_shift($values);
            // print_r($keys);
            $fields = [];

            foreach ($values as $row) {

                if (!empty($row)) {
                    StrAdaptator::f($fields, 'event', $row[array_search('Event Name', $keys)]); //colonne A
                    StrAdaptator::f($fields, 'type', $row[array_search('Event Type', $keys)]); //colonne B
                    DateAdaptator::f($fields, 'date', $row[array_search('Event Date', $keys)], DateAdaptator::YYYYMMDDshort); //colonne C
                    StrAdaptator::f($fields, 'city', $row[array_search('City', $keys)]); //colonne E
                    StrAdaptator::f($fields, 'firstname', $row[array_search('First Name', $keys)]); //colonne F
                    StrAdaptator::f($fields, 'lastname', $row[array_search('Last Name', $keys)]); //colonne G
                    EmailAdaptator::f($fields, 'email', $row[array_search('Email', $keys)]); //colonne H
                    StrAdaptator::f($fields, 'phone', $row[array_search('Phone', $keys)]); //colonne I
                    PhoneAdaptator::f($fields, 'E164', $row[array_search('Phone', $keys)]); //colonne I
                    StrAdaptator::f($fields, 'socialMediaHandle', $row[array_search('Social Media Handle', $keys)]); //colonne J
                    StrAdaptator::f($fields, 'musicalGenre', $row[array_search('Musical Genre', $keys)]); //colonne K
                    StrAdaptator::f($fields, 'market', 'B2C'); //colonne L
                }
                try {
                    Agnostik::sql_insertUpdate('events', $fields, self::WITH_SQL_LOG);
                } catch (PDOException $e) {
                    echo "\r\n" . 'PDO Exception: ' . $e->getMessage();
                }
                print_r($fields);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: _the blank cells are replaced by the above data_ ?? I dont understand what that means. Can you provide an example please. Also the schema for the table would be useful so can you add the output from a `SHOW CREATE TABLE YourTableName;` for us to llok at please

Comment: I edited my post with 2 screenshots and I explained

Comment: Maybe you mean its keeping the value from the previous `$fields` occurance. So if thats the case try emptying `$field` with a `$fields = [];` just after the IF

Comment: @RiggsFolly I would say **before** the `if` rather, or after the `try..catch`. If the OP misunderstands and put if between the `if` and the `try..catch`, it will insert all empty values..

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure to understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you don't reset `$fields` on each loop turn, so when `$row` is empty, it stays with the previous values.

Either try with the follwing modified code, or add a `else` if you need to specifically insert null values using `$fields`.

```
            foreach ($values as $row) {

                $fields = []; //Move this line inside the loop

                if (!empty($row)) {
                    StrAdaptator::f($fields, 'event', $row[array_search('Event Name', $keys)]); //colonne A
                    StrAdaptator::f($fields, 'type', $row[array_search('Event Type', $keys)]); //colonne B
                    DateAdaptator::f($fields, 'date', $row[array_search('Event Date', $keys)], DateAdaptator::YYYYMMDDshort); //colonne C
                    StrAdaptator::f($fields, 'city', $row[array_search('City', $keys)]); //colonne E
                    StrAdaptator::f($fields, 'firstname', $row[array_search('First Name', $keys)]); //colonne F
                    StrAdaptator::f($fields, 'lastname', $row[array_search('Last Name', $keys)]); //colonne G
                    EmailAdaptator::f($fields, 'email', $row[array_search('Email', $keys)]); //colonne H
                    StrAdaptator::f($fields, 'phone', $row[array_search('Phone', $keys)]); //colonne I
                    PhoneAdaptator::f($fields, 'E164', $row[array_search('Phone', $keys)]); //colonne I
                    StrAdaptator::f($fields, 'socialMediaHandle', $row[array_search('Social Media Handle', $keys)]); //colonne J
                    StrAdaptator::f($fields, 'musicalGenre', $row[array_search('Musical Genre', $keys)]); //colonne K
                    StrAdaptator::f($fields, 'market', 'B2C'); //colonne L
                }
                try {
                    Agnostik::sql_insertUpdate('events', $fields, self::WITH_SQL_LOG);
                } catch (PDOException $e) {
                    echo "\r\n" . 'PDO Exception: ' . $e->getMessage();
                }
                print_r($fields);
            }
```